# Which function will be called on starting an activity with a click on notification with a pending intent if the activity is already running

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I want to open an activity when user clicking on a notification. I can do it with a pending intent which works fine even if the activity already running. But I want to do some thing on the click operation. now I am doing that in `onCreate` method. it only works when the activity not running. I tried with `onNewIntent` method which is not reaching on above condition. What I can do now ?

Comment: onNewIntent gets called only if activity's launchMode is set as 'singleInstance'. pls see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#LaunchModes

Comment: if I set activity's launchMode as 'singleInstance' I couldn't able to receive activity result from this call `startActivityForResult`. Do you have any solution for that ? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @VnyKumar your comment is NOT correct. `onNewIntent()` will also be called if the launch mode is `singleTop` OR if the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is set in the Notification `Intent`.

Comment: Please post the code you use to create the Notification and also your manifest.

Comment: I fixed it @David Wasser. By adding intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); this flag for the activity inside the pending activity.      As you said.

Comment: Great. Please create an answer and select it as the correct answer so that this question will not be in the "unanswered" list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68317/discussion-between-sakkeer-hussain-and-david-wasser).

Comment: Your answer looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTIFICATION_ID =>    A number used to identify the notification to do further operations.
mContext        =>    Application context.
ResultActivity  =>    Activity to be opened.

```
    //creating intent
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, ResultActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("update_request", true);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    //creating pending intent
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        mContext,
        0,
        resultIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

    //Build the notification using Notification.Builder
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)  //adding pending intent
    .setContentText("content");

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
   (NotificationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //Get current notification
    Notification mNotification = builder.getNotification();

    //Show the notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

Now you can do your operations on `protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)` function of the Resulting activity.

And you also can set the new intent as intent of the activity as `setIntent(intent)` from the `newIntent` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag in pending intent to update the current activity. And then implement your login in `onResume()`

Comment: Added the flag. Still not reaching `onResume`

Comment: I have a suggestion for you then, create a `BroadcastReceiver` in the activity and register it in the `onCreate` and `unRegister` it  in `onDestroy` send the broadcast intent when you receive the push notification. and implement your logic in `onReceive`. This is for the case when you are already on the same activity of pending intent

Comment: I fixed it man. By adding intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); this flag for the activity inside the pending activity.